# How to retrieve the sender smtp email address with Outlook interop?

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook

I'm using c# and Microsoft Outlook interop outlook dll to read and retrieve mails from Outlook (Exchange).

I'm facing issues in parsing the sender email address as the code returns the Exchange address rather than the plain email id. What i want to retrieve is like `username@abc.com` but the output of my code is the Exchange address of the email:

> (/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP
>   (xxxxxxxxxxx)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=XXXXXXX32AD740E69184DC03B2A406F4-XXX
>   XXX)

Code I have tried:

```
emailItem.Sender
```

and

```
emailItem.SenderEmailAddress
```

How do I convert the Exchange address to an smtp address or how do I retrieve just the smtp address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
string senderEmailAddress;

if (mi.SenderEmailType == "EX")
{
    senderEmailAddress = emailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress;                    
}
else
{
    senderEmailAddress = emailItem.SenderEmailAddress;
}
```

Where:

- `emailItem` is a [`MailItemClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitemclass.aspx)
- [`emailItem.SenderEmailType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.senderemailtype.aspx)  is a string representation of the *type* of the e-mail address of the sender of the Outlook item
- the [`Sender`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitemclass.sender.aspx) property returns an [`AddressEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.aspx)
- [`GetExchangeUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser.aspx) returns an [`ExchangeUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.exchangeuser.aspx) object that represents the `AddressEntry` if the address corresponds to an Exchange user
- And from there we can retrieve the [`PrimarySmtpAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._exchangeuser.primarysmtpaddress.aspx) (`string`).

This should work with Outlook 2010 and newer.